# What is the purpose of an inheritance tax when inheritance could be taxed like other income?

Tags: taxes, income

Many countries have special laws regarding inheritance taxes. Why would this be treated separately when it could just be taxed equally to all other income?

Suppose Eve normally earns €50,000 per year. Due to an inheritance, one year, Eve earns €150,000. Why do we need an inheritance tax — one could just tax an income of €150,000?

We might want to tax income one has worked for less than income one has not worked for, but this could be organised by declaring both income from labour and total income separately. However, it seems rather that in some countries, inheritance income one hasn't worked for is taxed *less* than income from labour. I don't see how that makes sense. Eve is not a charity.

There is a related question, *[What ethical (if any) or economical arguments are offered in defense of the inheritance tax?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/30292/130)*, but that one is sort of the other way around, because the asker seems to imply that inheritances should be taxed less than income from labour. If there is no inheritance tax ([Wikipedia lists various countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_tax) that have abolished them) it should be just taxed like all other income, I suppose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What ethical (if any) or economical arguments are offered in defense of the inheritance tax?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/30292/what-ethical-if-any-or-economical-arguments-are-offered-in-defense-of-the-inhe) I don't think the questions are different enough IMO

Comment: Close-voters: I have already explained in the question why I don't think the linked question answers my question.

Comment: Both Q's seem to be pretty much "why is inheritance taxed the way it is" followed by each of your opinions, which don't really matter. For example "when were cats domesticated? I think it was recently" is the same as "when were cats domesticated? I think it was very long ago".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

This answer is U.S.-centric, because that is what I know best.

**Why Have A Separate Gift And Inheritance Tax Regime?**

There are a number of reasons to have a separate tax on donative transfers (gifts, estate, and inheritances) from the ordinary income tax. In the U.S. tax code, gifts and inheritances are exempt from income taxation pursuant to 26 U.S.C. § 102, in order to clear the field for separate gift, estate, and generation skipping transfer taxes.

One big factor is **administrative convenience**. It is administratively easier for tax officials to monitor the estates of people who die to see if executors and trustees are paying inheritance taxes than it is to see if members of the general public are reporting gifts and inheritances that they receive. In the U.S. system, gift tax returns historically (until quite recently) were usually audited only when someone died further streamlining the process. It also assures consistent valuation supervised by an officially deputized fiduciary chosen for their administrative competence, rather than just an ordinary individual.

Closely related is that fact that the **transaction cost frictions associated with sporadic lifetime gifts** from individuals interfere with the behavior people would have in the absence of taxation much more than the transaction costs associated with business transactions and employment which are typically systemic, regular, on a scale that creates administrative economies of scale, in transactions that are not "optional" and must be conducted to provide the daily needs of the taxpayer.

The justification for a certain amount of tax free gifts is similar to the income tax standard deduction in the United States that frees a large share of taxpayers from the need to keep detailed records of their daily activities.

A third issue, related to the second, is that **there is a fine line between non-taxable expenditures for support of dependents and gifts**, which can be better defined in the context of a gift tax. But, any inheritance or estate tax needs to be backstopped by a gift tax to avoid making lifetime gifts a huge loophole to the inheritance or estate tax system. In the case of inheritances to minors or dependent children, this blurring of lines still exists.

A fourth issue is **lumping**. Inheritance and atypical lifetime gifts often involve amounts that are "earned" over a lifetime, but received all at once, while most kinds of income are received gradually, and those that are not, like capital gains, often receive special treatment to address the "lumping" effect.

**Why Use Different Tax Rates?**

For the most part, there is no compelling reason to tax inheritances and other income at different rates, and after exemptions, the current U.S. federal estate tax rate and the current maximum federal income tax rate are reasonable similar.

*Avoiding Under Taxation Of Capital Gains*

One argument in the U.S. context for taxing taxable inheritances at a higher rate than taxable income, as the law did in the early 1990s is that this makes up for a shortfall in income taxation. Many (and probably most) large estate taxable estates derive most of their value from appreciation in a closely held business, appreciation in real estate, and/or appreciation in investments that accrued substantial capital gains during the owner's life that were never taxed. But, due to the "step up in basis of capital gains at death" found in 26 U.S.C. § 1014, these capital gains are never taxed in the income tax system if the owner holds onto them until death. A tax rate on estates that is higher than the tax rate on ordinary income reflects that the estate tax is a combined tax in lieu of income tax on the heirs and a make up tax on capital gains of the decedent that were never taxed in a rough justice sense.

Capital gains from investments in real estate often go untaxed in the U.S. because the capital gain proceeds can be rolled over without triggering taxation into new real estate investments pursuant to 26 U.S.C. § 1031. So, these investments are only taxed when an investor cashes out out the investment real estate sector entirely.

Income from closely held businesses (and even publicly held businesses) is often taken in the form of stock and stock options that are only taxable, again, when they are "cashed out".

And, both stock in a business and investment real estate can be borrowed against in order to avoid triggering capital gains taxation prior to death when the taxes that would otherwise be due on the accrued capital gains are forgiven.

Other countries, like Canada, tax capital gains that have accrued at death, so this isn't a consideration there.

*Support v. Gifts*

On the other hand, part of the justification, beyond administrative inconvenience, for taxing gifts and inheritances at rates below what would be taxed in the income tax (often zero) is that this reflects the notion that modest inheritances are part of what emotionally amounts to a duty of support which is basically a debt, owed by the older generation to younger generations, just like paying for food, clothing and shelter for children at younger ages.

Historically, the non-taxability of support for children was codified at 26 U.S.C. § 71, but that was repealed when Congress enacted  Pub. L. 115-97, Sec. 11051 in 2017 which was fully effective on December 31, 2018 with some transition provisions in the interim. This is now treated as part of the definition of income for income tax purposes pursuant to 26 U.S.C. § 61, by implication since alimony and child support (including child support in kind) are omitted from transactions that constitute income, despite the fact that it is not a comprehensive list of all forms of income, and by 26 U.S.C. § 1041 which excludes from taxation transfers between spouses and transfers incident to a divorce.

*Preserving Small Businesses*

The tax free inheritance gap also reflects the fact that this can help preserve family farms and businesses, which are seen as socially desirable to continue.

*Competing Claims To Inheritances*

There is a sense that it makes sense to relieve small inheritances from taxation because they are subject to other claims.

In the U.S. context, there are two main such claimants that have some similarity to inheritance taxes.

First, in the U.S., working class and middle class people are often beneficiaries of the means-tested Medicaid program which while billed as a means-tested grant based program providing nursing home care and medical care to people who can't afford it, actually operates more like a government guaranteed loan. Medicaid keeps track of what it spends on beneficiaries and if they have enough of an estate at death to leave inheritances, Medicaid is a creditor at death with priority over heirs to the extent necessary to repay amounts advanced for nursing home care or medical care to the decedent during life.

Second, many states have costly probate systems in which the courts and executors and their lawyers receive a significant share of the estate, often on percentage of assets fee basis, in order to carry out the process of transferring assets from the decedent to the next generation.

Now, admittedly, these considerations made much more sense when the lifetime exemption from gift and inheritance taxes was $600,000 (about the 70th percentile for decedents when it was in effect due to lack of adjustment for inflation for decades)-$1,500,000 (about the 90th percentile for decedents when it was in effect) per person per lifetime, rather than $12,060,000 (about the 99th percentile for decedents today) per person per lifetime (with unused portions of the exemption inherited for use at a second death by the surviving spouse, as it is in 2022.

*Gift And Estate Tax Revenues Are Modest And Wealth Is Concentrated*

It is also the case that large donative transfers by gift and/or inheritance involve a much smaller tax base than earned and investment income. As currently constituted, gift and estate taxes provide [only about 1% of federal tax revenues](https://taxfoundation.org/estate-tax-provides-less-one-percent-federal-revenue/) in the U.S., and since the people who are subject to the current U.S. estate tax own about 35% of the wealth in the U.S., even if all inheritances were taxed as taxable income, this tax base would still account for less than 3-4% of federal tax revenues if taxed at the roughly the same tax rates as income, while requiring taxes to be paid by about 60 times more people (about 40% of people have so little net worth and so little income that including inheritances in income wouldn't give rise to taxable income even if inheritances were taxed as income).

Reducing the exemption from $12 million per person per lifetime to $1.5 million per person per lifetime would roughly double estate tax revenues from about 1% of U.S. tax revenue to 2% of U.S. tax revenue and would require roughly ten times as many people to file estate tax returns.

Furthermore, the donative transfer tax based in much more concentrated that the income tax base, in a small number of taxpayers, because it turns out that wealth is much more concentrated than income.

> Wealth inequality in the USA is even more extreme than income
> inequality and – like income -- it has become more unequal over time.
> In 1962, the wealthiest 1 percent had 125 times the wealth of a median
> household (Mishel et al., 2012, fig 6C). By 2010, this ratio had
> ballooned to 288-to-1. Between 1983 and 2010, the top 5% of wealth
> holders saw their wealth grow by 83%. The bottom 80% saw their wealth
> decline by 3.2% (Mishel et al., 2012)
>
> In 2007, the top 1% of US wealth holders owned 35% of wealth (up from
> 20% in 1971).
>
> The top 10% (including, of course, the top 1%) owned 73%. The bottom
> 40% of all US households owned just 4.2% of all wealth. The top 1%
> owns 60.6% of financial securities; the richest 10% owns 98.5% of
> financial securities, with the “bottom 90%” holding a mere 1.5 percent.

([Source](https://peri.umass.edu/fileadmin/pdf/working_papers/working_papers_301-350/WP302.pdf))

So, the amount of income that can be exempt from income taxes per person without making much of a dent in tax collections and saving the people who are exempt from taxation of lot of administrative hassles for themselves and the government alike, is much smaller, than the value of inheritances that can be exempt from estate taxes per person without making much of a dent in estate tax collections (again avoiding a great deal of administrative hassles for the decedent's estate and the government alike).

A very large share of all inheritances in any given year come from people who have net worths at death in the hundreds of millions of dollars and up, so exempting mere single digit millionaires from estate taxation doesn't reduce estate tax revenues all that much despite reducing the number of estate tax returns that have to be processed and the amount of tax planning for death that middle class and upper middle class people need to pay lawyers and accountants to do, profoundly (easily reducing administrative costs by 90% or more while perhaps reducing estate tax revenues by 10% or less).

The great concentration of wealth allowing a small number of taxed individuals to provide most of the tax revenues from the taxation of gifts and inheritances also figures into the first question of why it doesn't make sense to tax gifts and inheritances as just any other kind of income.

The game of tax policy is to get as much revenue with as few complaints from the people being taxed as possible, and exempting 99% of potential taxpayers while reducing revenues collected from the transfers only modestly serves that practical policy consideration very well.

*Ideology*

Some critics of low taxation of inherited wealth attribute this change to "neo-liberal" policy ideologies (*see, e.g.*, Tim Koechlin, "[The Rich Get Richer: Neo-liberalism and Soaring Inequality in the United States](https://peri.umass.edu/fileadmin/pdf/working_papers/working_papers_301-350/WP302.pdf)" at pages 24-29) defined in this way (in footnote 16 at page 24):

> Neoliberal “policy makers are committed to free market policies when
> they support the interests of big business… But these same policy
> makers become far less insistent on free market principles when
> invoking such principles might damage big business interests”.

Neoliberalism, so defined, however, does not unequivocally equate with low taxation of inheritances and neoliberalism, unlike anarchism or strict libertarianism, recognizes that some significant level taxation is necessary for a well functioning economy and society.

Comment: The point about Medicaid is interesting. Why did this consideration make more sense when the lifetime exemption was much lower? Are the Medicaid claims covered by the lifetime exemption, or do you mean Medicaid never competes with inheritance tax because nobody who has an estate en excess of the exemption would be eligible for Medicaid?

Comment: @gerrit The point at which Medicaid ceases to be a factor because people with greater net worth don't qualify is in the ballpark of $600K to $1500K (the value of a modest house in a high housing value area plus some retirement funds). So, refraining from imposing inheritance tax then simply respects a different program's claim. But at $12M per person per lifetime, there is a big gap between Medicaid/probate costs as a big consideration and estate tax considerations where neither apply (and capital gains tax minimization is the main goal).

Comment: I was mixed when I started on this answer. It seemed like it was headed nowhere and I was going to downvote. That changed around by the "why different rates" section, making a wash in my mind. But then this summary paragraph is really the gold in here: *"The game of tax policy is to get as much revenue with as few complaints from the people being taxed as possible, and exempting 99% of potential taxpayers while reducing revenues collected from the transfers only modestly serves that practical policy consideration very well."*

Comment: I'll try reading again the first parts...

Answer (score 48):

Historically, inheritance was a family affair
The family being a single economical unit, spanning generations. Parents and children working together for the common survival, as a farm or small business.
The concept that society has inherited (pun intended) is: Inheritance is not income, it is just redistribution of common wealth within the same family. Each heir has already worked to create this wealth, the family income has already been taxed.
The concepts of family, income, state, tax etc. have evolved, the importance of private income, individual wealth and inheritance has changed, as well as the relations between parents and children.
What is just (or should be) regarding inheritance and taxation seems to be the core of this question. My answer can only be: whatever society decides. I gave some explanation how the current state has evolved. How it will evolve further is how society as a whole may answer the question.

Comment: I like this answer, because it points out how, culturally, we consider the family as a unit and the wealth to be property of the family as a commune rather than to the individual.  And I believe that in many countries, if I inherit money from a total stranger, I pay more tax on it than if I inherit from my parents.

Comment: Most importantly, the concept of property has evolved. A farm or small business is usually not owned in the form of stocks, neither did that family own hundreds of rental units.

Comment: @gerrit: Yes, absolutely. For example in Germany, there is a certain amount that is tax exempt ("Freibetrag") - between partners it is 500,000€, for childern 400.000€, but for strangers it is only 20,000€. In France, the situation is roughly similar, only the sums are significantly lower. I'd assume most other countries are similar

Comment: There's also the historic viewpoint that the people who would be leaving large amounts of money were the ruling classes... and then subsequently the people who were able to vote when things became more democratic. So taxing inheritance heavily would be something that would reduce a government's chance to be re-elected.

Comment: "Each heir has already worked to create this wealth", hahaha

Comment: @njzk2 Have an ungrateful son, do you? A prodigal that already took his half?

Comment: @frеdsbend ? I'm just saying that people don't typically work toward the wealth of their parents

Comment: @njzk2 Maybe not as much in your experience but, for example, having a farmer's children help out around the farm was, at least historically, expected. The same goes for many businesses, be it a corner shop or plumber - some help is still likely to be provided by family and help towards the progression of that wealth. I expect the examples you're thinking of are where the parents work salaried jobs?

Comment: @njzk2 Forget farmers. Good children help their parents all the time, including maintaining and improving property. This behavior starts young too, when they begin taking chores. This concept of family building and preservation is ancient. If you're so detached from it, or jaded, that's only your experience, not universal.

Comment: @frеdsbend: I think the background of the "hahaha" is that if you look at about 70-90% of the *volume* of inheritance, it is to about 0.5-1% of the *persons* that inherit this bulk. Those persons didn't typically do much for that wealth, it just happened they've been born into families that own so much that the sheer amount of wealth produces more wealth (and increasingly so since about the 1990s), *often for generations*. Incidentally, they do pay about 1% inheritance tax if any at all as opposed to the heir of more mundane sums who usually pays 10-30% taxes.

Comment: Many of the largest inheritances were not grown by the family.  People like Commodore Vanderbilt, Joe Kennedy, most of the "Royals" in the world.  A patriarch built the fortune and left it to the family.  The kids inherit and fail to grow the money but do little with it that is useful to society.  Of all the Vanderbilts, only Gloria Vanderbilt created a major business.  The only reason the Royals still have their fortune is because they pay 0% tax on it (every year, and during inheritance).  Most of the lower income people have inheritance sheltered by cutoff below which the inheritance is 0%

Comment: @boatcoder Those fortunes are invested and they do pay taxes on the interest. Those investments do something for society, namely, provide lending opportunities for others.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Sour grapes over a handful of people. Millions of people more benefit relatively massively from their relatively small inheritances.

Comment: I think the parents/children arguments are obscuring the more important point that the wealth was _already taxed_.  If it was income, it was taxed as income.  If it was capital gains, it was taxed as capital gains.  To tax inheritance is to tax money that was already taxed when it was produced.  I'm not arguing for or against this practice, just pointing out the fact.

Answer (score 27):

(this answer is a bit meh)

You could tax it the same way, but people don't want that.

Inheritance is *different*.  People don't choose to inherit. People can't change their behaviour to inherit more or less, or earlier or later.

Generally different forms of income are taxed differently. Capital gains are taxed differently from income (and capital gains on property are taxed differently again). Gambling winnings have a different tax system. Severance pay is not taxed the same as bonuses.

The government sets a tax system that it thinks can be "sold" to a public (who want public service, but would rather not pay tax) can raise money from those who are able to pay and doesn't harm those who can't.  The tax system must raise enough money to pay for public services without being so unpopular that the government gets voted out. To walk this tightrope, government find it necessary to tax different forms of income differently.

But *Meh* the government could tax inheritance the same as other income, but it might not stay in government long if it did.

So the answer is *political* not *economic*.

Comment: *So the answer is political not economic.* (double-checking) That's why I asked this on [Politics.SE] and not on [Economics.SE] :)

Comment: Sounds like Arnos comment on the question is the real answer, then.  Most people will never have a large inheritance, so the next question would be why the inheritance tax serves a rich minority... but OK.  Good answer, not very meh :)

Comment: In Germany, one CAN indeed refuse an inheritance, and I think this is often done when it is likely that the desceased person left net debts (for which the inheritor would otherwise be liable). I think the decision deadline after the death is not especially long, but I can't recall.

Comment: @kpollock: Yes, it's called [Erbausschlagung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erbausschlagung), and the deadline is usually six weeks after learning of the inheritance.

Comment: "People can't change their behaviour to inherit more or less, or **earlier** or later." Arguably, you could change your behaviour to inherit earlier, but if you did we'd be talking about it on the Law SE site...

Comment: @DBS: There are many legal ways, at least in the US, for people to adjust the timing of when wealth is passed between generations.  As a simple example, people whose inheritance would otherwise be taxable may opt to make maximal-sized gifts to their children every year so as to avoid having those funds taxed as inheritance.

Comment: *People don't choose to inherit* They do, at lest in may EU countries where you can refuse an inheritance.

Answer (score 18):

> Suppose Eve normally earns €50,000 per year. Due to an inheritance, one year, Eve earns €150,000. Why do we need a special inheritance tax — one could just tax an income of €150,000?

Suppose instead that Eve inherits €5,000,000. The taxes on that as a one year income would be immense. Moreover, that €5,000,000 represents income her parents earned on which they had already paid taxes. In one sense, it would be unfair to tax that already taxed income. However, in another sense, those large inheritances represent a key factor in wealth disparity. Many countries allow some amount to be passed down generation to generation tax free but do tax what are deemed to be excessive inheritances.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140834/discussion-on-answer-by-david-hammen-what-is-the-purpose-of-an-inheritance-tax-w).

Answer (score 18):

Inheritance may be a bank account or stock portfolio. But often it involves things like a single-family home, or a small business. Taxing this at the same rate as income would force the inheritor to sell it off and re-invest the remaining inheritance, which is seen by the public as undesirable.

Of course, as mentioned in the comments, public opinion is shaped by those with an interest to try and shape it. In [germany](/questions/tagged/germany) one perfidious issue is the mix-up of *Mittelschicht* (middle classes) and *Mittelstand* (small and medium businesses, i.e. no more than a couple hundred employees). Any attempt to tax the *Mittelstand* owners gets portrayed by the *Mittelstand* lobbyists as an attempt to tax the *Mittelschicht*. And members of both the upper end of the lower class and the lower end of the upper class like to self-identify as middle class.

Comment: OP doesn't think income and inheritance should be strictly taxed at the same rate as explained in the question. But yes, making it a different tax is more intuitive.

Comment: "would force the inheritor to sell it" Doesn't have to. Often one can pay due taxes in rates over time if the amount of taxes to be paid is so high.

Comment: @Trilarion Paying off over time is not always a possibility. A small farm in Western Europe, for example, is usually just about surviving. If the next generation has to pay half of its value when inheriting, what do they do? Sell half the fields? Same for a small business, do they sell half of the workshop or the equipment?

Comment: @RedSonja A small farm in Western Europe usually doesn't have to pay half its value in inheritance taxes. There are quite big allowances in these inheritance schemes usually. On the other hand, if your business is not profitable, you may be doing something wrong anyway. It's just another cost factor. If a small farm is just surviving, chances are high, it won't survive long anyway, because of some yet unforeseen event. The idea is rather that the inheritance would be paid over time from the running profit.

Comment: @Trilarion Well, I was a farm kid. A small farm or business invests its surplus in the business. Having to pay yet another tax would force them to sell up. No-one benefits from that. Well, the big farming concerns do, they get the land cheap and employ cheap labour to produce the cheap stuff supermarkets want. Some people may find that good.

Comment: Most non-factory farms aren't profitable in part because food production is so cheap with a factory farm. Whether we should subsidize buggy whips might be a different argument, but historically, in the United States, we've subsidized the idea that people can make a living from farming despite the changing landscape. Possibly not helping things is that land value is different if you're growing corn, or Walmart wants your lands, so the taxes may exceed the "worth".

Comment: Your example doesn't seem relevant. Businesses are typically owned by multiples of people, except for very small ones, and its only the partial ownership that passes by inheritance, not the whole of it. But never mind that, the example doesn't even seem to be about *inheritance* taxes, but business income tax, with a little swirl of personal gripe mixed in.

Comment: @frеdsbend, numerically small and medium businesses (and their owners) far outnumber large companies. I have no idea about the total value of either group, but for my point is is sufficient that individually owned businesses frequently become part of an inheritance. Homes are even more frequent, so I mentioned them first, but there are something like 3 million family businesses in Germany. Do the maths how often one gets inherited, on average.

Comment: @o.m. Sure, owned business is inherited, but you're still not talking about that. You're just complaining about lobbyists playing on similar words. Lobbyists whom I'm sure talk a lot more about business income taxes than anything else.

Comment: @frеdsbend, my first paragraph acknowledges a *legimitate* need to treat inherited homes and businesses differently from income. My second paragraph mentions a specific case where German lobbyists use a confusion between terms to mislead voters. I consider both relevant to the politics of inheritance tax in Germany.

Comment: Even taxing it at the rates at which many countries do tax it forces the sale of those assets. E.g. the Netherlands taxes inheritance to direct family members at 25%, to all others at 50% (which is higher than the highest income tax bracket for most people btw.). If I inherit a 300k home (which is quite low in the current market) from my father I'd pay 75k inheritance tax on it. That's likely to be more than the entire monetary part of the inheritance post-taxes for many people.

Comment: @jwenting I assume if you inherit a 300k home you could put a 75k mortgage on it to cover inheritance taxes?

Comment: @florian: Would be trivial, especially if you plan to live in it. Only downside: mortgage interest is tax-deductible in the Netherlands _when the mortgage is used to purchase a primary residence_. This isn't a purchase. Also, the Dutch percentages are wrong. It's 0% for the first 20K, 10% for the next 130K, 20% for the last 150K, total 43K, not 75K.

Comment: @RedSonja If some business asset is worth 2 million dollars, and it is being put to optimal use, it will be generating more than (debt on 2 million dollars interest) profits.  Or nobody would pay 2 million dollars for it, so it isn't worth 2 million dollars.

Comment: @Yakk That's not how real estate works. *That* market is so much more inflated than just two decades ago. It might be assessed today at $2M, but was purchased and leveraged for much less. This is mostly why young companies don't own their building.

Answer (score 7):

As stated by [James K](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/76771) and alluded to in other answers, you can make the case that inheritance is a very special kind of income. Inheritance resembles donations, and some countries will use the exact same tax for donations and inheritance.

Once you agree inheritance is a singular way of obtaining assets, creating a special tax out of it has some procedural advantages for a government:

- You can choose **different collectors** for the new tax. For example, in Brazil, inheritance tax is collect by states, while regular income tax is collected by the federal government.
- You can choose **different taxpayers**. In inheritance, the heirs or the deceased person's estate can pay for the tax, while in income tax it is more intuitive that only who gets the income pays.
- You can choose **different rates**. You can have lower/higher rates to incentivize/penalize capital accumulation within families.

Of course, all these different rules could be integrated to income tax laws and we could call everything income tax. But since people intuitively understand the difference between regular income and inheritance, it is easier to create a new tax with an appropriate name.

Answer (score 7):

The tax has to be payable. Society won't accept a tax where many people can't receive their inheritance because of taxes.

To rebut your point about separate taxes favoring the roch and their huge inheritances, consider this. Eve actually makes 20k per year and lives in a house in poor neighbourhood with her mother. Her mother dies and the house is appraised to be worth 100k.

If those 100k were taxed just like anything else, Eve couldn't pay the tax and should sell the house to pay it. She'd end up even worse, likely renting for the rest of her life.

But society does not accept such system because they think they should be able to leave their belongings to their family after they pass away.

Comment: "She'd end up even worse, likely renting for the rest of her life." I kind of agree with you but just for playing devil's advocate here, renting isn't that bad. Many people do it. And the house was her mother's who only let her live there. Why should it be hers now? On the other hand it's not clear why inheritance as income must be counted in a single year. It could count as income distributed over many years for example. That would alleviate many of the mentioned problems. And finally inheritance taxes exist, she might lose the house anyway.

Comment: Hmm. But Eve's parents, and probably Eve herself, have spent part of their income maintaining the house and garden. They have had the roof and windows replaced, installed new heating and wiring as needed. They have invested many unpaid hours. Renters will not do this. Also, Eve may already be retired herself and have a very low income.

Comment: I personally think my children and grandchildren should benefit from my living sensibly. They should certainly benefit more than people whose parents spend all their income on wine, women and song. Otherwise why would I bother betting out of bed at all?

Comment: @RedSonja I don't think you can show a logical basis why that should be true. That appears to be your own self-interest wrapped up in the veneer of a moral principle.

Comment: @user253751 arguing for moral absolutism is not a winnable argument.

Comment: @AdamBarnes nor is moral relativism based on pure self-interest

Comment: @user253751 [enlightened self-interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlightened_self-interest) is about as close as you can get to moral relativism.

Comment: @AdamBarnes RedSonja's comment isn't enlightened self-interest - it's just self-interest with the facade of a moral principle.

Comment: Self-interest is what gets us all out of bed in the morning. I want to eat more than just bread. I want my kids to be healthy and happy. I want everybody's kids to be healthy and happy. Yes, because it makes me feel good.  Nothing moral about it. It's selfish, I suppose.

Comment: @user253751 You can't think of a logical reason that taxing schemes should favor the buildup and preservation of successful families over hedonism?

Comment: @RedSonja If self-preservation is now defined as selfish, we've entered the twilight zone.

Comment: @user253751 the taxes (or exemptions from taxes as in this case) don't have to be right or to have a logical basis. They just exist because that's what the lawmakers and voters prefer to have over the alternatives. In this case people want the ability to leave their stuff to their family more than they want to tax the rich.

Comment: my niece ended up in effectively that very situation through a different structure. She lived with her parents in a rental property and was kicked out of it by the rental agent the day her father died because the rental contract was in his name. She's been living with her brother ever since because there's simply nothing she can afford to rent on her nurse's income.

Comment: @Džuris and that's a fine answer (possibly not the best) but RedSonja specifically presented a specific case of their own self-interest (not just self-preservation) as some kind of universal moral principle. It's like saying "I personally think that all user+number accounts on Stack Exchange should get free reputation as a reward for increased anonymity" - it's nonsense, the only reason I'd say it would be to get some free reputation, and yet it's presented as if it's some kind of principled take.

Comment: @user253751 you're making absolutely no sense.

Comment: @RedSonja and others: feel free to answer over on [philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/94897/why-should-one-receive-special-benefits-as-a-result-of-their-ancestors-having-ce)

Comment: I was just thinking that.

Comment: @Trilarion "Why should it be hers now?" Why should it be anyone else's? If you're not using your car right now, that means I can just stop by, take your keys, and then use it myself, right? I mean, you're not using it at the time, so why I can't I? Or a different analogy, I really really need to make a phone call. I'm sure you've got a phone, so I need to use it, thanks.

Comment: @Džuris "people want the ability to leave their stuff to their family more than they want to tax the rich" It's really easy to have both. Simply do a progressive inheritance tax with say a free amount of a million $. That way you have both. Taxing the rich is completely uncoupled from feeding the poor and less well off.

Comment: I find that example rather misleading: such problems can prevented by allowing a generous tax free amount on the inheritance. I guess most people who want an inheritance tax don't want to tax a single house, but as a tool to reduce huge unfairnesses in the wealth distribution.

Comment: @Hans-PeterStörr By "allowing a generous tax free amount on the inheritance" you simultaneously say that inheritance will be taxed differently than the other income.

Comment: @Džuris Ah, good point! If you'd weave that into your answer - that treating it like normal income would make it impossible to have a sufficient tax free amount for that very common scenario - then your answer would be surprisingly compelling.

Answer (score 6):

Most people don't inherit, or very little. They don't pay inheritance tax anyway.

Inheritance is a form on wealth building that is mostly used by the already wealthy family. It builds wealth along generations.

Financial power gives political power, which in turn gives political advantages.

Having a low tax rate on inheritance is maintained because rich get rich, and poor stay poor. Same thing for capital gain taxes which is lower than the highest income tax bracket in all the countries I know about.

Income tax is progressive (in most countries), and affects only low to upper-middle classes. Anyone above that receives dividends and capital gains, and doesn't pay income tax, or very little.

Comment: When my parents were young, houses were cheap.  People on a modest income could buy their own house.  Now houses are expensive.  The only way many young people can ever own their own house now is to inherit it.  High taxes would take that away - anyone inheriting a house would have to sell it to pay the tax.

Comment: A lot of experts disagree with you. For example: *"... inherited wealth isn’t a huge driver of inequality in America — it actually has had an equalizing effect. And there’s no indication that the next decades will be any different. The reason is deceptively simple: While much (much!) more money flows among the rich, for middle- and low-income people who receive gifts or inheritance, they represent a larger percentage of wealth. So large, in fact, that for some people, a gift from mom or dad is the thing that will keep them middle class."*

Comment: [Source: vox](https://www.vox.com/the-highlight/22320272/inheritance-money-wealth-transfer-estate-tax). Combined with the facts that inheritance will affect approximately 25% of people, inheritances in excess of 10 million (I believe, in the USA) *are* taxed, so those nasty rich people are getting taxed on it.

Comment: @SimonB So there would be more houses on the market, which should drive down prices, which would make them more affordable, which would be a good thing? I've rarely heard of people not selling the house they inherit. Many people who do inherit have already bought a home by the time they inherit from their parents, by which time they're probably in their 40s or 50s, because even without inheritance, the offspring of rich people are often rich.

Comment: @SimonB there would be more houses on the market and therefore prices would be lower if they could not be inherited. Children of rich parents would have to buy them with money, instead of just keeping the family mansion.

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer. Philosophically, we want to be advanced beings, but actually we are still dominated by our ancient instincts. You are putting in your question the highest point of view where every member of the society is an individual and their wealth belongs only to them; passing that wealth to their children is like passing it to other individuals. But the laws are still affected by the tribal mentality; the wealth of the individual is also the wealth of the family.

Comment: And another ancient mentality is at work, too: Envy.

Comment: @EvilSnack are you referring to the poor homeless child being envious of the rich private school student? That indicates a real problem with society and is not just some bullshit fake instinctual thing.

Comment: @user253751 Eliminating inheritance rights will not affect the rich private school students one bit. They'll just find themselves on a board of a trust fund with a big salary and an even bigger golden parachute, or something along the lines. It's the not-so-poor regular school students who will be at risk to go homeless once their parents die.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev isn't that why it only kicks in above a certain amount? besides which, be realistic: the children are going homeless anyway because children can't rent apartments.

Comment: No, I am referring to the ancient habit of some people who are doing okay, but are resentful that others are doing better.

Comment: Maybe it's intentional this answer is so small, but there's certainly a lot to be said about the individualist outlook driving the question, and that the opposing outlook *is* well understood and preferred by many. I'd suggest there's a few pages of subtext that could be said about the question in this answer. +1 for bringing it up.

Comment: "we want to be advanced beings" Do we want actually? Or are we just becoming unhappy by pointlessly trying? Stating that we have evolved instinct favouring a particular kind of behaviour, instead of dismissing it, is actually stating that such approach has been for so long a winning strategy, that it become hard coded.

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that some jurisdictions recognize the possessions of a married couple as *community property* (jointly owned by both) and others only recognize *separate property* (everything is owned by one person).  If property is treated separately, then the death of one spouse means that the surviving spouse would have to pay a potentially-huge amount of taxes simply because their assets moved from one spouse's name to another.  That doesn't seem fair, especially since the same property would be transferred tax-free by something like a divorce settlement, or by moving to the next state over which is a community property state.  The death of a spouse is already hard enough, and forcing the widow to then sell the house in order to cover the tax consequences of losing her husband is borderline cruel.  It also makes it difficult for the breadwinner of the family to ensure that their family's basic needs can still be met should something happen to them.

Also consider the traditional case of a family farm, particularly a subsistence farm.  The entire family works to maintain it, and being a subsistence farm, they have practically no income.  Normally, they pay no taxes on no income.  Once the family patriarch dies, the survivors inherit the farm and suddenly they show a *massive* income that year (farms are quite valuable) and owe a whole pile of taxes.  They have no real income as subsistence farmers, though, so they're forced to sell the farm and no longer have any means to support themselves.  A significant fraction of the population were subsistence farmers for most of our history, so a situation like this would quickly lead to disaster.  It's far better for people to remain able to provide for themselves than to end up living on government support.

It's easy to come up with a lot of situations like this where people generally agree that the consequences of taxing the inheritance as income would be undesirable.  Carving out exceptions in the tax code to address these sorts of situations would get complicated very quickly, like an endless game of whack-a-mole.  Instead, creating a separate estate tax that's fine-tuned to handle inheritance and nothing else is a much simpler solution that's easier to understand and implement.  It also helps smooth out the differences in how each state views ownership of marital property (i.e., your *federal* tax burden doesn't change just because your *state* laws are slightly different).

Comment: This is not true between spouses in the U.S. There is an exclusion from income taxes for transfers between spouses 26 U.S.C. § 1014, and both the gift tax and the estate tax have marital eductions (unlimited for citizen spouses and subject to some restrictions for non-citizen spouses if made without using a qualified domestic trust). There has never been a time in U.S. history where a subsistence farm without substantial non-farming development or mineral rights value has been valuable enough to be subject to U.S. gift and estate taxation resulting in actual taxes due. That's a myth.

Comment: @ohwilleke I'm only saying these are problems that could occur if we *didn't* have gift/estate taxes and inheritances were considered ordinary income.  We don't see them in our current system because - as you point out - we have a separate estate tax system that ensures that they don't.  I'm simply pointing out that doing it that way is significantly simpler and more efficient than shoehorning a million special cases into an already overcomplicated income tax system.

Comment: As to the differential rates, yes. But inter-spousal transfers are very often tax exempt including in the U.S. income tax system as well as for transfer taxes.

Answer (score 5):

Several possible reasons, which go a bit along the same lines as [James K's answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/76771/11727):

- Larger inheritances (which would mean higher taxation in most progressive-rate taxation systems) are linked to rich people. Rich people are powerful. They will make sure you don't get re-elected if you mess with their family's money.
- There is competition between countries on taxes. If the taxes are too high, people may consider moving to a different country (for real or to to try to trick the taxman). Given that many countries have low or no taxes on inheritance, you don't want to frighten people off too much, or they're going to move and just not pay any taxes at all.

A few more reasons:

- Inheritances are not necessarily cash, liquids assets, or non-productive assets. If a business is to be inherited, you usually wouldn't want the family to have to sell the business just to pay the taxes, so such assets need to be either excluded or taxed less.
- There are a lot of different circumstances: leaving a house or flat to your partner and school-age children should not cause unnecessary burden to them, while an inheritance where the children are all adults well established in life could be taxed more. You need to have a special taxation system to (try to) take these situations into account.
- People feel they have worked hard to "make sure their children are safe", have already paid taxes on that income. Taking money from them again can be quite sensitive.

Comment: Regarding the bullet about trying to parse out whether inheritors *need* the inheritance, what a can of worms. I'd rather 10 people get an inheritance they don't need before we tax someone who does.--- +1 for presenting various ideas.

Comment: "Inheritances are not necessarily cash" There have been life insurance markets to address this in eras where it has been a concern and also often payment plans or exceptions to general rules. "There are a lot of different circumstances: leaving a house or flat to your partner and school-age children" inheritance taxes with low exemptions usually make these distinctions as do laws on the priority of creditor's claims at death v. surviving family, but in jurisdictions like the U.S. where the exemptions are large, this isn't usually done (except for surviving spouses).

Comment: @ohwilleke That's really the whole point I'm trying to make: if inheritance was just income like any other, it would be difficult to carve out those exemptions, while it's a lot easier when you have separate inheritance and income taxes, with different rates, thresholds, rules, etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Loophole abuse**

The thing about regular tax methods, is that there are deductions you can take - for income tax, stuff like charitable donations, political donations, tax shelters, stock investments, government bonds, loans, etc.

Thing is, that's generally palatable because the income tax is meant to get the government money to provide services, sometimes towards direct services that complement the government, towards election supports, or investments into the economy.

Thing is, the leftover income from inheritance is, in part, from money already taxed, but, crucially, *also* applied those same deductions. And you neither want to double tax it on the previous taxes, as that would be unpopular, but...you might have reason to tax on those deductions. Since when the inheritor inherits the money, *they* weren't the ones who made the donations that had been exempted...and are about to inherit it now.

As a result, you, as a government, likely have more room to negotiate different ways to "Loophole" around a situation, or to put limitations on the inherited flow of money based on the fact that it has, potentially, already been deducted from taxes before.

EDIT To Add: Or as a **TL:DR; Some people may had only wanted you tax money they deducted over their dead body - as a government, you get to take them up on that offer.**

Answer (score 3):

So I saved a lot of money to pay my six children's way through colleague. But unfortunately I die before they are old enough. And suddenly the tax man wants half the money that I saved for them and they will have to give up on their eduction because it's not enough money. Doesn't seem fair, does it?

BTW. The kids still live at my house and I provide for them. So not only do they lose the person putting the food on the table, they also have to pay a good percentage of the value of their home.

Another thing completely unfair with your suggestion: In most countries, rich people are supposed to pay a higher tax rate. But a $150,000 inheritance to a 20 year old doesn't make them "rich". It's just $5,000 for each of the following 30 years. So at the very least I would request that an inheritance can be paid out over time, and tax handled accordingly.

In Germany, it's quite common in wealthy families that inheritance goes to grandchildren or grand grandchildren, because that means the some money doesn't get inherited again for a very long time. A 90 year old multi-millionaire won't leave the money to his 70 year old child, or 50 year old grandchild, but his 10 year old grand grand grandchild. So the taxman doesn't get money again for 80 years hopefully.

Comment: Any system in which access to education depends on the wealth of the parents is unfair.  One proposal I've seen (maybe it was Piketty) was to tax inheritance and put the proceeds in a fund from which *all* 18-year-olds can draw to get a college education (or some other categories of spending that are deemed useful investments, like buying real estate or starting a company), not only the fortunate kids with parents who were able to save up for giving their kids better chances than other kids. Instead of Universal Basic Income one gets Universal Starter Capital.

Comment: @gerrit Inheritors are typically much older than 18. That idea is kind of like proposing my local tire guy pay more taxes so someone else's kids can get free college. I'm American, so I'm steeped in the property rights ideals here, but unless you're from an old communist bloc, I don't see how you can have such a cavalier approach to private property preservation.

Comment: @frеdsbend I don't see anything wrong about your local tire guy paying more taxes to make access to education more democratic.  Private property preservation when people die is impossible, because dead people can't own things.  The question is merely about *how* to redistribute the wealth of people who have died.  There's nothing communist about paying education primarily from taxes rather than charging children or their parents, unless you would call Germany and France communist.  But now we're really getting off-topic here.

Comment: @gerrit The tire guy and everyone else already received free primary and secondary education. But then when he chooses a path that neither uses nor needs tertiary education, you believe it's fair he help pay for others who do make that choice? Yes, actually, belief that blue collars should have less property protection and more taxes to benefit explicitly not them is hallmark communism. The only this you're missing is telling him he has to work for free (for everyone's benefit, of course).

Comment: @frеdsbend Yes, I believe it's fair that he contributes to the costs of tertiary education. If he ever visits a doctor, he benefits. If he uses a road that some engineer designed, or enters a building that some architect came up with, he benefits. If his children go to school and enjoy qualified teachers, they all benefit. And although I'm not sure what profession the "tire guy" has, manual jobs also involve (vocational) tertiary education. This is not communism. In communism there exists no state, no private property, no money, and no taxes.

Comment: Some of those doctors, teachers, and architects might still be there if the state didn't use tax money to pay for their education. Others would not, because they might not be able to afford to. Society needs doctors, therefore, the barriers to becoming a doctor should be based on individual skills, not on whether one had rich parents who "saved up for college".

Answer (score 3):

Stability of income is probably the best argument. Consider three people Alice, Bob, and Carlos:

- Alice has a modest income in a normal year (i.e. without any inheritance), and then in one year receives an okay inheritance
- Bob has a large income in a normal year (i.e. without any inheritance), and then in one year receives the same inheritance
- Carlos has the same income as Alice in a normal year, but doesn't receive any inheritance

If inheritance was taxed in exactly the same way as income, then for one year Alice's tax rate would go up massively, closer to what Bob's is. But this seems to violate two of the justifications for taxing inheritances and income:

1. A major justification for taxing inheritances is to reduce the possibility of a wealthy elite simply reproducing themselves, arguably with negative repercussions on democracy and meritocracy. But Alice hasn't become part of the wealthy elite simply by receiving an inheritance. She will most likely go back to earning a modest income in future years. The gulf between Bob and Alice remains higher than a simplistic yearly income calculation would imply.
2. We expect income tax to be based on some sort of ability to pay. Naturally, Alice's ability to pay has gone up compared to Carlos', but probably not as much as might be thought - she probably has bills she's able to pay off or now able to do household maintenance she'd previously put off as too expensive. Maybe she gets her first real holiday away from a stressful job in a long time. Those are all things Carlos isn't able to do... but they're also the sorts of basic quality of life things that ought to be the norm in a developed country. It's not perfect, but when we tax income there's a rough, background assumption that people's incomes year-to-year tend to be stable. Including inheritance into income tax then would mismeasure people's ability to pay, because a one-off jump in their income doesn't increase ability to pay as much as consistently earning a larger income year after year.

So basically we need to tax inheritance to some extent, but it needs to be treated differently to income because Alice is more like Carlos than Bob. And since we do still want to tax inheritances, we can still justify taxing Alice a bit more than Carlos, just not as much as an integrated system.

One final thing - I don't think the "what about the family home" arguments in other answers are particularly strong, since there are often exemptions/reductions for those sorts of things now, and there's no reason why an integrated system couldn't do a similar thing. I've focussed purely on abstracted financial wealth, as I think that's the heart of the matter.

Answer (score 1):

At least in the United States, there isn't much choice but to create a separate category for it. Taxing it as earned income would destroy family farms and overly encourage wasteful spending near the end of people's lives. Taxing it as unearned income would be too low a tax rate for large estates.

Answer (score 1):

Treating inheritance as income would create a huge difference between inheriting a property and (for instance) getting the same property as a gift from your parents.

People would have a choice of either gifting most of their assets to their children (perhaps using complex contracts which limit what the children can do with the assets while their parents are still alive), or penalize their children with an income tax. Furthermore, such contracts would have to be regularly updated as parents acquire new assets, and it would be especially complicated when such assets are sold or otherwise disappear. E.g. moving to a new house would become really complicated for retired people who presumably already have gifted their old house to their children.

Inheritance makes such situations more manageable, while still preserving the ability to pass wealth to the next generation within a family. Notably, the issues mentioned above essentially don't exist for rich people who have a family lawyer anyway, but would be a harsh strike for the poorer families.

Comment: *Treating inheritance as income would create a huge difference between inheriting a property and (for instance) getting the same property as a gift from your parents* — why? Receiving gifts is also income. However, they could avoid high taxes by spreading the gift over a long period, this is true. I'm not sure what the relevance of poor families is; poor people have no inheritance. We're talking middle class and above here.

Comment: @gerrit In U.S. law both gifts and inheritances are excluded from the definition of income. 26 USC § 102. But, while the question was not carefully stated in this regard, I think the intent was to imagine (in the U.S. context) a repeal of Section 102 which exempts both gifts and inheritances (collectively called donative transfers) from income  taxation, and the repeal of gift and estate taxes, simultaneously.

Comment: @ohwilleke Even still, I'm pretty sure there's a maximum number that can be gained tax free by either gift or inheritance, in the USA. So there are taxes, just only sometimes.

Comment: @fredsbend There are gift, estate, and generation skipping transfer taxes in the U.S., but there are not income taxes on gifts and inheritances.

Comment: How does excluding gifts not create a giant loophole for tax avoidance?  The employer could give a nice gift to all their employees every month because they're no nice; no matter their salary looks 50% lower than for other employers…

Comment: @gerrit That's not the only loophole, there are also "loans" which your employer doesn't expect to be repaid, "benefits in kind" like free to use company cars, etc. Tax regulations are constantly being adjusted to make sure disguised remuneration is still treated as such.

Comment: @gerrit Essentially, a gift is only treated as such if there's no consideration expected in return. If you give a gift of money to a car shop and later receive a car as a gift from that same shop, the tax office will find out eventually.

Comment: Couldn't one close all those loopholes by treating all gifts as income?

Comment: @gerrit, in the UK I believe any presents that the employer gives you will count as taxable income. Many years ago someone found a loop hole: A gold sovereign had a market value of say £100, but it was legal tender with a face value of £1. So one employer paid his employees in gold sovereigns at face value and bought them back at market value. So the employee got £99 less income and less tax accordingly. I think it was not illegal but the loophole got closed ASAP.

Comment: @gerrit, a gift is a transfer with no strings.  A regularly scheduled 'gift' given in exchange for X hours per week of labor will bring an employer into an unhappy interaction with the tax authorities in the US, but I'd imagine there would be a similar skepticism applied by tax authorities to this 'gift' in most other countries as well.

Comment: @ohwilleke I see, I was fixated on estates as inheritances colloquially. There's no federal inheritance tax (cash received by inheritance), but six states do tax it, however the feds do tax inherited estates for their value over $12M. [Source](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/inheritancetax.asp). --- Gifts are taxed over $16K. That the feds call it "gift tax" and not "income tax" is irrelevant to the tax prayer; he still must pay.

Comment: The OP isn't asking for the differences between inheritance tax, income tax, etc. He's asking why inheritance isn't taxed.

Comment: Worth saying that aiui in Ireland, their version of inheritance tax includes gifts during lifetime too. And in the 1970s, the UK had the Capital Transfer Tax instead which did the same thing.

Comment: @frеdsbend To clarify, I asked why inheritance isn't taxed like other income. I was under the impression that would be the default _unless_ there exists a special inheritance tax that exempts inheritance (or gifts) from regular income tax. After all, if the tax man asks how this €200k entered my bank account, I'd have to show them that it's inheritance and therefore not subject to income tax?

Comment: @gerrit If you're looking for the nitty-gritty with definitions, then you're on the wrong site. Law would be better, or personal finance.

Comment: @ajd138 I assume this was done because people started to do what I have described: gifting some of their wealth to their heirs in order to reduce the inheritance tax.

Comment: @gerrit Sure you could. It would also mean that cancer patients who got donations for their treatment would have to pay a tax. And then one could argue that couples in which only one person works should pay more tax because the other person takes care of the household for free, essentially donating their time to other family members. It could really go a long way.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Charitable donations are already tax-exempt in many legislations, this would surely cover charities help to cover cancer treatment when coverage by insurance or universal health care is insufficient.

Comment: NB: In The Netherlands, gifts for the poorest are already essentially taxed, because if social security finds out someone bought groceries for you, they will cut your benefits. Of course, this only covers poor people, not rich or middle-class people, because rich people have lobbies and middle-class people have votes, so only the poor are penalised if they receive gifts. I would hardly be surprised if they started to penalise "someone cleaned your home for you" as well.

Answer (score 0):

An aspect that is never mentioned when it comes to inheritance tax is that inheritance is a service offered to the heirs by the government.  Real estate is recorded with the government and only exists because there is a government record of the ownership. These records need to be updated for the new owners.  The tractor on the farmland belongs to the heirs because government guarantees it.  Stocks lie in some banks vault.  The banks must transfer the ownership to the heirs.  Government obliges them to.  Same for savings accounts.

One way of thinking about inheritance tax is that it is a payment for this service.

Comment: This answer rather argues for a general property tax. On the other hand, keeping that database (of who owns what) updated is probably not that expensive. The typical inheritance tax is probably much higher much beyond covering only the costs of the service.

Comment: Software also costs more than the cost of the data transfer.
Yes, a similar point of view could be taken towards a property tax (or most other taxes), but a transfer of ownership when the previous owner is dead clearly has its unique challenges.

Comment: What about jewellery or rare stamps that the government does not 'manage' for you?  Would your eagerness to tax extend to a Bitcoin inheritance?

Comment: @Trilarion The government provides not only a database, but also a band of mercenaries (hireable thugs) that will come to your aid (for free!) if reality differs from how the database says it should be. That probably costs quite a bit.

Comment: @KalleMP as you noticed, I deliberately chose examples which don't involve thek ind of physical possession that you can carry in your pockets but a kind of contractual obligation that has to be transferred to the new owners. As for your example of Bitcoins: you still need someone to determine the rightful heir to the wallet, so I don't think there's an automatism where you can say "for this class of assets, government doesn't play a role."  Nevertheless, and as for my "eagerness" to tax, I think it is consistent with this point of view to exempt small inheritances from the obligation to pay.

Comment: BTW I'm not giving my opinion, I'm giving an alternative point of view to evaluate an estate or inheritance tax against. In my personal opinion, I shouldn't pay inheritance taxes but every inheritance larger than mine should be taxed till it hurts :)

Comment: You seem to be describing a "recording fee" for putting the transfer of property in the public record, but that is entirely independent of the inheritance tax. And how does paying the government a tax serve as payment to a completely unrelated entity like a bank transferring assets to heirs? I don't think there's much argument to be made that inheritance tax is essentially an administrative fee.

Comment: This is an argument for taxing inheritances, but the question is asking why we don't tax inheritances as a subset of the income tax which this answer doesn't address.

Comment: I think it's an argument for why inheritance taxes are categorically different from income taxes. As for the question why to pay the government and not the bank: the government forces / obliges the bank to do the transfer. It's the government, not the bank, that keeps the inheritance if there are no heirs, after all.

Comment: After writing this, I remembered an example of what happens when government doesn't take care: Swiss banks kept the assets of Jews who disappeared in the holocaust https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volcker_Commission

Answer (score 0):

Hoarding wealth is how hereditary aristocracies form. It is not in the public interest of democracies to allow such aristocracies to exist. Part of why we had a revolution in 1776 was to get away from aristocracies. The simplest explanation is that such accumulation of wealth is "not fair". If you think your offspring "deserve" such money, give it to them before you die - you have plenty of time and there are plenty of ways to dodge this tax (and other taxes).

The [Rule Against Perpetuities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_against_perpetuities) was another legal doctrine to prevent the permanent hoarding of such wealth by making it harder to transfer wealth to relatives who had not been born at the time of forming the trust. Under common law, the longest term that a trust could last was "someone alive plus 21 years" (example: your grandchild who was just born, their entire life and 21 years beyond that). Legal changes in some states, such as Florida, have replaced such restrictions and allowing trusts to last 360 years. The Rule Against Perpetuities is covered in the business law courses that accountants take. Everyone hated this subject.

Inheritance taxes do not affect the "bottom 99%" of the population of any country. Due to clever propaganda, such as [using emotionally laden words such as "death tax"](https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2010/12/16/132031116/a-history-of-how-we-got-from-estate-tax-to-death-tax) (this started in the 1940s), many people have been deceived to believe that they will be affected by those taxes. If you don't like inheritance taxes and don't want to pay them, then give you wealth away before you die. Our current version of inheritance taxes were legislated in 1916 ([history and explanation of some of the laws involved](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-soi/ninetyestate.pdf)).

> *The federal government has taxed inherited wealth in various ways since the nation was founded. The first time was in 1797, when lawmakers used a tax on wills and other legal documents to help pay for the nation’s “Quasi-War,” a low-grade, undeclared naval conflict with France. The second time came during the Civil War, when a new federal estate tax helped fund the Union war effort. A third time came in 1898, when the estate tax revenues helped pay for the Spanish-American War.*

[Source](https://www.forbes.com/sites/taxanalysts/2016/09/08/the-estate-tax-used-to-be-sort-of-popular-even-with-republicans/?sh=1a2641ef65d9).

In the US, in 2022, you can inherit up to $12,060,000 before you pay a penny in tax ([this will rise to $12,920,000 in 2023](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/estate-tax)). Not all states have an inheritance tax ([map showing which states have such a tax](https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/taxes/inheritance-tax)). Were you married at the time of death? Half of what you have goes directly to the spouse - that's before considering the twelve million dollars. Opponents of estate & inheritance taxes like to provoke sympathy by mentioning something like "family farm" and how it would have to be sold to pay taxes. No such thing has ever happened. When trying to identify such family farms, the closest I could find were farms where none of the inheritors wanted to "farm" - they all wanted to cash in. Additionally, "family farm" is type of corporation structure. Next time you are in the frozen food section of your grocery store, notice the frozen chicken - Tyson foods is a "family farm".

In short, you should have a [will and testament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_and_testament) before you die. If you don't, each state has a default version embedded in their laws. There is a huge industry of lawyers and [CPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certified_Public_Accountant)s who help wealthy people transfer wealth to their families in ways to avoid taxes. These are generally called "trusts". I'm all in favor of that. *Do it before you die*. I've met too many men who refuse to make wills because they don't want anyone to know what they have. Their widows (common refrain "he took care of everything, I don't know where any of the money is.") and children spend years trying to get stuff straightened out and none of them had enough to pay any sort of inheritance tax. Charles Dickens mocked such a situation in the novel *Bleak House* with a legal case called *"Jarndyce v. Jarndyce"*. In this case, there was a huge inheritance, but legal proceedings lasted decades and legal fees ate the entire inheritance. This still happens. Especially when there aren't wills and one (or more) spouses, ex-spouses, children or others claim in legal proceedings that they deserve it, or they should have gotten it, or that they were promised it, or many other arguments for why they should get some.

Comment: "No such thing has ever happened" - I actually have family members that this has happened to, within my lifetime.  It's definitely not just an abstract hypothetical.

Comment: *"Hoarding wealth is how hereditary aristocracies form. It is not in the public interest of democracies to allow such aristocracies to exist. Part of why we had a revolution in 1776 was to get away from aristocracies. The simplest explanation is that such accumulation of wealth is "not fair"."* That doesn't hold up. The level of freedom from what you are calling aristocracies is leaps and bounds from what the American rebels had to deal with in Europe. Money may afford you more power, usually by way of media influence, but unless you suggest cheating, it's still only 1 person, 1 vote.

Comment: The $12M figure is on *estates*. An inherited estate valued over $12M at the time of the owner's death will be taxed as income on the difference. Cash, on the other hand, is passed through.

Comment: Yeah, *"No such thing has ever happened"*??? No, it hasn't happened lately because it's not taxed and hasn't happened since such taxes have been disallowed. It has certainly happened in the past, and one would be a fool to suggest it won't happen if the tax was instituted again. In fact, even in comments on here, people are saying they *should* be made to sell it.

Comment: In Finland if you donate you pay a tax.  Also half of your estate is shared amongst your descendants even if you will other wise.  If you donate to some of the descendants then it is assumed to be early-inheritance and managed accordingly.  If I have two kids and donate everything to one and then die things can get complicated.